# Completeness results for Categorical Quantum Mechanics restricted to one $\dagger$-Frobenius Algebra?

Tags: ct.category-theory, stochastic-processes, frobenius-algebras, stochastic-matrices

I've seen the various completeness results for Categorical Quantum Mechanics (CQM) axiom systems involving two interacting Frobenius algebras with various restrictions of phase-nodes. For example, the ZX-calculus is complete for pure qubit stabilizer quantum mechanics: https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.7025.

I've also seen that the restriction of the the ZX calculus to a single Frobenius algebra (call it, say, the Z-calculus) seems to capture at least some of the category of Stochastic matrices, Stoch: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.1997.pdf, but I'm curious if there are any completeness results floating around for this fragment? Can we show that we can capture exactly Stoch, or is it possible the axiomitization misses something?